# Debian kernel upgrade from 3.2.0.4-amd64 to 3.12.0

Tags: kernel, debian, upgrade

I tried to create the kernel from 3.2.0.4 to 3.12.0 according to the following instructions.

```
cd /usr/src/linux
tar -xvjf linux-3.12.tar.bz2
cd /usr/src/linux/linux-3.12 
make defconfig
make menuconfig
cd /usr/src/linux/linux-3.12/
make clean    
make bzImage
make modules
make modules_install
cp /usr/src/linux/linux-3.12/arch/x86/boot/bzImage /boot/bzImage-neu
cp /usr/src/linux/linux-3.12/System.map /boot/System.map-neu
cd /usr/src/linux/linux-3.12
update-initramfs -c -k 3.12.0

vi /etc/grub.d/40_custom

#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.


menuentry "bzImage-neu" {
        set root=(hd0,1)
        linux /bzImage-neu root=UUID=9f4c876a-d160-4c04-8093-53925f00121f ro
        initrd /initrd.img-3.12.0
}


update-grub
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message

```
Gave up waiting root device.  Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/disk/by-uuid/9f4c876a-d160-4c04-8093-53925f00121f does not exist
Dropping to a shell!
```

Can someone help me in solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After saving your configuration you should run `make dep` to build the dependencies. If you need to recompile the kernel run `make mrproper` to remove the saved configuration then `make dep`.

The easy way to compile a custom kernel on debian:

```
cd /usr/src/linux/linux-3.12 
cp /boot/config-`uname –r`.config
make menuconfig
```

Just verify the *Enable Loadable modules..* is selected, save and run:

```
make-kpkg clean
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --revision=1.0.custom kernel_image
```

The new image is installed , Remove the new entry from `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and update grub:

```
update-grub
dpkg -i ../linux-image*
```

More info on:

- [Kernel Image Management](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/i386/ch08s06.html.en)
- [kernel-handbook.](http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-building)